# I can't purge old kernels because of unmet deps

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, dependencies

I'm trying to free space on disk, because when I try to install anything I get back

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-133-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-133-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-64-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Also when i try to remove old kernels I got same message. Ofc I tried -f and other techniques from this answer [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)  But nothing help. Any clue how can i remove old kernels and get rid of those unmet dependencies?

Comment: If you tried `-f`, post its **full** output.

Comment: My goodness. HOW have you been trying to remove old kernels? This seems a likely problem with your method.

Comment: @fkraiem I found that it stands for 'fix'

Comment: @user535733 with dpkg -r

Comment: Then seems like you have been uninstalling in the wrong order, or leaving packages installed while removing their dependencies. `dpkg -r` requires a careful, methodical, double-checking approach. It's easier to use `apt`, when possible. Try uninstalling `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-133-generic` and `linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-64-generic`. Use apt to reinstall `linux-image-generic` so it picks up the correct dependencies.